# Using Loader with SherlockActivity show error in initLoader(o, null, this);

Tags: java, android

I'm facing problem with `initLoader()` while using Loader. Its not taking the third argument null. Can any one help me to fix the error?

> ERROR MESSAGE:: The method `initLoader(int, Bundle,
>   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>)` in the type LoaderManager is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int, null, TestActivity)

And this is my code.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import utilcontentprovider.F1DatabaseMetaData.TeacherTableMetaData;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;


public class TestActivity extends SherlockActivity 
             implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listId = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your imports refer to the support package so you should use `getSupportLoadManager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()`.

Change

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

with

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Comment: where is getSupportLoaderManager()? I can't find it.